# Чем отличаются static, self и parent в php?

Tags: php

Собственно хотелось бы увидеть различие работы со `static::` от `parent::` и `self::`

Comment: @BOPOH Ну хоть есть нормальные люди, а то любят всучить манул мол кури, а что там написано и сами не знают (такое ощущение будто гугл открыли и первую ссылку дали в ответ). Ваш ответ меня очень устраивает, хотелось бы спросить, просто я в мануале не видел создание объектов через self, parent, static (Где можно подробнее почитать, если есть конечно)

Comment: создание объект, по сути, ничем от вызова метода не отличается, поэтому не уверен, что в документации это описано. Я вам пример привел же во втором комменте - там и объекты создаются. И по этому примеру уже видно, что лучше `new static()` использовать (иначе не понятно будет, почему в классе B получили объект родительского класса A). И ни разу не видел, чтобы parent использовали именно для создания объекта (вызов конструктора родительского класса в конструкторе дочернего не считается), хотя это и возможно

Comment: @BOPOH Не так давно начал изучать именно ООП(php) отсюда следовательно вывод, почему я спрашиваю такие вопросы
Как я понял статик используется **для** дочерних классов, чтобы знать где идет вызов, так ведь?

Comment: если я вас правильно понял, то вы правильно поняли ))) self - только этот класс и никакие другие, даже если есть наследование. static - именно тот класс, который используется, даже если static был прописан в каком-нибудь далеком родителе. А parent работает так же как и self, только для родителя - т.е. он вызывает родителя именно того класса, где этот parent написан, т.е. если есть классы O -> A -> B и parent есть в классе A, значит будет вызван родительский класс именно для A (т.е. O)

Comment: @BOPOH я из ваших комментариев собрал ответ. :) Дополняйте.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`parent` - вызываем родительский метод (не обязательно статичный), `self` - вызываем метод именно этого класса, `static` - вызываем метод текущего класса. Разница между `self` и `static` хорошо видна, например, когда вы делаете `new self()` или `new static()` - в первом случае будет создан объект класса, где упомянут `self` (т.е. создан родитель), во втором - объект того класса, где вызывается метод (т.е. потомок)

примеры можно посмотреть [здесь](https://ideone.com/kSHhvk). "когда применять" - всегда, если только вам не нужен именно текущий класс, а не его наследники. Не знаю когда это может понадобиться, поэтому можете использовать static всегда, потом меньше проблем будет )

в документации можно почитать [эту статью](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php), там как раз описано отличие static и self и прочее

(ответ перенесён из комментариев [BOPOH](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/5079/bopoh))

Comment: Не мое дело конечно, но вам не кажется неправильным получать репутацию за человека который это написал? Хотя этот пост я плюсану

Comment: @MaximPro я с вами полностью согласен, поэтому отметил ответ как "общий". Такой ответ не приносит репутации автору. Подробнее читайте тут: http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/2436/181472

Comment: Не знал о таком! Тогда все ок :)

Comment: @MaximPro, если бы я отвечал на все вопросы, где пишу свои комменты - у меня и рейт был бы больше )) А если бы в свое время (еще на ХК) мои комменты не преобразовывали бы в ответы - у меня было бы около 1К рейтинга. А все потому, что меня рейт мало волнует ) К тому же - я где-то уже писал, что если из моих комментов кто-то соберет нормальный ответ - я не против, даже если ответ будет не общим, а от имени определенного человека

Comment: @BOPOH Понятно, но ведь чем больше рейтинг тем больше привелегий различных

Comment: @MaximPro, а зачем они мне? ) набрать нужный рейтинг не сложно, когда понадобится - тогда и наберем, а пока не вижу в этом смысла ))

Comment: @BOPOH Я вас понял =)

Answer (score 22):

> Пример отличия "static::" от "self::". Создадим класс 'Model' (базовый) и дочерний 'Users'
>
> 1) В этом случае "self::" находится в родительском классе, следовательно берет данные
>   из родительского(от туда где он находится).

```
class Model {
   public static $table='table';
   public static function getTable() {
      return self::$table;
      }
    }
class User extends Model{
      public static $table='users';
   }
   echo User::getTable(); //выведет 'table'
```

> 2) В этом случае "static::" берет данные из вызывающего класса, в нашем случае 'Users'.

```
class Model {
   public static $table='table';
   public static function getTable() {
      return static::$table;
      }
    }
class User extends Model{
      public static $table='users';
   }
   echo User::getTable(); //выведет 'users'
```

> 3) И здесь "parent::" используется для доступа к методам и свойствам базового (родительского) класса. Здесь мы, в дочернем классе, переопределили
>   метод базового класса( foo() ), но с помощью "parent::" все еще можем
>   обратиться к родительскому методу.

```
    class Model {
       public static $table='table';
       public static function foo() {
          echo "1_test";
          }
        }
    class User extends Model{
           public static function foo() {
          echo "2_test";
          parent::foo();
          }
       }
echo User::foo(); //выведет '2_test1_test'
```

Answer (score 10):

**self** — класс в котором написано.

**static** — класс в котором выполнилось.

Например, если вызвать унаследованный метод в котором self / static, то каждый вариант даст разный результат.

[Late Static Binding](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php).